# Django2 での画像1枚1枚への閲覧制限のかけ方

Tags: python3, django

Django2の勉強中のものです。

＃＃＃

今、Python3 / Django2 / Pillow で画像管理サイトを作っているのですが、
画像１枚１枚に対して、ユーザー毎に閲覧制限をかけたいと思っています。

試行錯誤で、django の view.py の中で pillow と bytesIO を使って、
何となく実現の方向は見えてきました。
閲覧権限が満たされていたら、pillowで画像ファイルをopenし、
byteIOへsave、そして、byteIO.getvalueで HTTPResponse に書き出しと
１枚の画像のHTTPResponseを返すのに手間がかかりすぎているように感じてます。

＃＃＃

もっとスマートに「画像ごとにユーザー閲覧権限」をかける方法はないでしょうか。
アドバイスをいただけますと、嬉しいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 画像をバイトではなく、ファイルとして取り扱う

  - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
- 対応するURLへのアクセスにユーザーの認証を必要とさせる

  - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/
  - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests

というのでいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。
参考になりました。

static-files で静的ファイルへのアクセスを開いた後、ひとつひとつの対応するURLへユーザー認証を必要とさせる方法が、実はむずかしくてわからないです。（初心者ですみません）

staticへのアクセスURLがあればだれでもアクセスできることを避けたいと思っています。実現方法がわからなくて、今悩んでいます。